# Is normality a strict requirement for maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, normality-assumption

I'm having some trouble understanding a few things with regards to ML estimation - suppose I wish to use this method to estimate the  parameters of a multivariate model and that the data sets of each variable are not normally distributed or they are almost normally distributed, does this mean that my estimation would not be correct? would I have to take into account the distribution when using ML, what if the distribution is undefined or unknown?

Also, is this the same case as least squares regression? Is normality a requirement there?

Answer (score 2):

You probably are looking at maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) of OLS problems, linear regressions. In textbooks they always show how under normal distribution of errors assumption MLE is equivalent to OLS. In practice MLE is applied to all kinds of distributions such as Poisson, for instance. So, no, you do not need normal assumption in every case.

On the other hand, if you do assume normal distribution but the true distribution is very different from normal, then you may not get good results at all. It depends on how different is the true distribution from normal, and there's no simple (standard) way of determining this deviation and its implications, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm actually looking at a highly non-linear recurrence relation; somewhat similar to a VAR model, my data is looks almost normal however it does have quite fat tails  and in some instances a t-distribution would describe it better (but not in all) and so i'm wondering if an MLE under normal assumption is used, would my results be incorrect or sub optimal?

Comment: @Arman, you have a problem I outlined in the second paragraph of my answer: there's no easy way of telling if normal assumption would work well or not. You may try to study this by running monte carlo simulations. Generate the data under non-normal assumption, then estimate it with Gaussian MLE, compare to true values, repeat. That's what people do anyways

Comment: Thanks for your replies, they've been very helpful. Let me know if i'm correct here, so the assumption of normality of a model is on its errors/residuals?

Comment: Yes, the assumption is about the errors and their correlations too, which are usually assumed to be zero (for a random sample)